# jQuery slider issue

Tags: jquery, html, slider

I'm very new to jQuery and so I have tried to follow this [tutorial](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#side-scroll) then later tried to adjust it to my own. But I'm not very succesfull.
First of all i have the same slider more times on same page. The first slider works correctly
but the other slider wont work. If you scroll it will just continue a bit so you se the background instead of the pictures. If you want to se the site live instead here [it's](http://evvephotodesign.com)
and i dont know if its a css issue :S

Heres the html code:

```
div id="sliderTab1">                        
        <div class="scroll-pane">
            <div class="scroll-content">
                <?php include("designRetouch.php")?>
            </div>
            <div class="scroll-bar-wrap">
                <div class="scroll-bar"></div>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
```

and 3 more times.

heres the jQuery for the slider scrollbar and how to show the slider

```
        function sizeScrollbar(){
        var remainder = scrollContent.width() - scrollPane.width();
        var proportion = remainder / scrollContent.width();
        var handleSize = scrollPane.width() - ( proportion * scrollPane.width() );

        scrollbar.find(".ui-slider-handle").css({
            width : handleSize,
            "margin-left":-handleSize/2,
        });
        handleHelper.width("").width(scrollbar.width() - handleSize);
    }
```

and...

```
$("#tab1").click(function(){
        $('li[id^="tab"]').removeClass('current');
            $("#tab1").addClass('current');

        $('div[id^="sliderTab"]').hide();
            $('#sliderTab1').slideToggle('slow');
    });
```

Comment: I didn't see a slider on the page.  Are the sliders named the same?  You need their id's to be unique and you would need to have the jquery handle the 2 sliders.

Comment: FYI, using `id^=` should probably be replaced by using a common class name.  Remember, you can have more than one class name on an object.  If you use a common class `"tab"`, you'd have `li.tab` instead of `li[id^="tab"]` in your selectors.  Both more readable and probably performs better too.

Comment: have you visted the site? then you will se my problem. I can se my slider but the problem is with the handler and when you finished to scroll throuhg the picures? 

the id's unice, sliderTab1, sliderTab2 etc and tab1, tab2, etc is <a> tags links. 


Whats the different between using class and id?

Comment: i fixed tha handle problem, i only needed to sett handleSize to 100, which means 100px

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem by made a single page for each slider
Didn't find out what the problem was, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

With out testing it out, but from similar experience, you'll need to give each sliderTab a different id such as

Then you'd need to run the jquery function initialized to run each one, such as:

```
 $("#tab1").click(function(){
    $('li[id^="tab"]').removeClass('current');
        $("#tab1").addClass('current');

    $('div[id^="sliderTab"]').hide();
        $('#sliderTab1').slideToggle('slow');
});

$("#tab1").click(function(){
    $('li[id^="tab"]').removeClass('current');
        $("#tab2").addClass('current');

    $('div[id^="sliderTab"]').hide();
        $('#sliderTab2').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

and so on. at least thats where i'd start.